# simple jQuery validation failed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to validate my value, but doesnt quite work if someone could help me out

```
function countrySelectChanged() {
    $('.sub-menu').hide();
    var selectedCountry = $('#country-select').val();
    if (selectedCountry) {
        $('#' + selectedCountry + '-select').show();
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $('#country-select').change(countrySelectChanged);
    countrySelectChanged();

    var valid;

    $('#click').click(function(){           
        if ($("#us-select").val() =="" || $("#germany-select").val() ==""  ){
            valid = false;
        } else {
            valid = true; 
        }

        if (!(valid)) {
            $('#msg').html('NOt Passed')
        } else {
            $('#msg').html('Pass')
        }
    });    
});
```

Here is HTML

```
<select id="country-select">
    <option value="none" >---</option>
    <option value="us" >US</option>
    <option value="germany">Germany</option>
</select>

<select id="us-select" class="sub-menu hide">
    <option value="none" >---</option>
    <option value="austin"  >Austin</option>
    <option value="austin2"  >Austin2</option>
</select>

<select id="germany-select" class="sub-menu hide">
    <option value="none" >---</option>
    <option value="berlin">Berlin</option>
    <option value="berlin2">Berlin2</option>
</select>

<select id="none-select" class="sub-menu hide">
    <option value="none" >---</option>
</select>

<a href="#" id="click">click me</a>
<div id="msg"></div>​
```

This is online version

http://jsfiddle.net/RPWPZ/14/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/SJ7Sg/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/95zXa/

To get the selcted option you need to do this `$("#us-select option:selected").val()`

**API** => http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Rest it should fit the cause `:)`

**code**

```
function countrySelectChanged() {
    $('.sub-menu').hide();
    var selectedCountry = $('#country-select').val();
    if (selectedCountry) {
        $('#' + selectedCountry + '-select').show();
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#country-select').change(countrySelectChanged);
       countrySelectChanged();

    var valid;

    $('#click').click(function(){

   if ($("#us-select option:selected").val() =="none"){

      valid = false;
            }else{
      valid = true;

   }


 if (valid) {
      $('#msg').html('Success')
       return false;
  } else {

      $('#msg').html('Fail')
  }


});


});






​
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,if i select two countries, not quite right `$("#us-select option:selected").val() =="none" || $("#germany-select option:selected").val() =="none")` http://jsfiddle.net/SJ7Sg/2/

Comment: @Olo no worries glad it helped `:)` Oh and why will you add above condition? `:)` i..e what exactly is the condition you are trying to parse, lemme know I will make the change or help you out `:)`

Comment: @olo `:)`I reckon this is what you mean - **Try this** http://jsfiddle.net/95zXa/

Comment: could you please tell me how to make the `---` to disabled but always shows on the top? I made the first line to `<option value="none" select="selected" disabled="disabled">---</option>` seemed not working. http://jsfiddle.net/95zXa/1/ thanks a lot

Comment: what is the difference between` $("#"+$("#country-select option:selected").val()+"-select option:selected").val() =="none"` and  `$(#us-select option:selected).val() ||$(#germany-select option:selected).val()  `

Comment: @olo Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/WPvGr/ - **Explanation** for the other part is - I am dynamically created the `ID` based on your selected country, because in any case either germany or us will be none! hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#country-select').val() =="us") {
  valid = false;
} else
```

Answer (score 0):

you must change 
`$("#us-select").val() =="" || $("#germany-select").val() ==""` 
with 
`$("#us-select").val() =="none" || $("#germany-select").val() =="none"`

because your default value of select is "none" ->

`<select id="country-select">
    <option **value="none"** >---</option>
    <option value="us" >US</option>
    <option value="germany">Germany</option>
</select>`